# Error in free() in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, free, maze

I think is something related to: If you save a pointer to an object allocated on the stack, that object goes out of scope, and then you modify something through that pointer, you can corrupt someone else's memory.

Im implementing a RandomMaze and a Pacman game.
I have one map ( maze) with an bidimensional array, where i put the corridor, walls, food and postition of pacman and ghost. In that map i know if pacman can move to the east, north etc..
Then using opengl i have to "make the animation": it moves from x,y pixels in screen....

So in the main file i have a global varible called Maze m; and i pass it to a mypacman.moveEast(m,s); ( screen has the widht, and height of the screen to draw all). Problem is ( i supposed) that i use m inside the operation, and somehow it calls a free() instruction because out of scope ( i guess it).

Any ideas would be apreciated..

```
vector<Ghost> playingGhosts;
Maze m;
Pacman myPacman;
Screen s ( WIDTH,HEIGHT);
Ghost Blinky, Pinky, Inky, Pokey;
int ghosts = 1;
long last_t=0;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    m.setupMaze(ROWS, COLUMNS, LEVEL);
    m.printMaze();
    //myPacman.set_position(m.getRows(),0);

    /*Esta función es la que inicializa la GLUT y negocia con el sistema de ventanas para abrir una. Los parámetros deben ser los mismos argc y argv,
     * sin modificar, de la función main(). Además, Glut entiende una serie de parámetros que pueden ser pasados por línea de comandos.*/
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    /*En esta ocasión, utilizamos GLUT_DOUBLE en vez de GLUT_SIMPLE. Esto hace posible la utilización de la técnica de “double buffer”, con la utilizamos
     * dos buffers para pintar en uno mientras se visualiza el otro. Con esto conseguimos una mayor fluidez en escenas.
     */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);

    //Posición x e y de la esquina superior izquierda de la nueva ventana, con respecto al escritorio en el que se trabaje.
    glutInitWindowPosition(WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y);

    //Comprobamos que el ancho y alto de nuestra ventana es menor que los pixeles de la pantalla.
    //En ese caso no cabria nuestra ventana en la pantalla
    if ( glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) == 0 || glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) < WIDTH)
        throw out_of_range("Error: El ancho no puede ser cero. Error ancho pantalla");

    if (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) == 0 || glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) < HEIGHT)
        throw std::out_of_range("Error: El alto no puede ser cero. Error alto pantalla");

    //El ancho y alto de la nueva ventana.
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    // Esta función es la que propiamente crea la ventana y el parámetro es el nombre de la misma.
    glutCreateWindow("Random Maze");



              //Ghost g;
            //  g= new Ghost();
              int x= m.getRows();
              int y =m.getColumns();

             // playingGhosts.push_back(5,7);// Esto esta en mapa hay que traducirlo a pantalla o al reves...insertar en pantalla directamente
              /*g.set_positionMap((x/2) - 1, (y/2) -1); // Blinky
              playingGhosts.push_back(g);

              g.set_positionMap((x/2) - 1, (y/2)); // Pinky
              playingGhosts.push_back(g);

              g.set_positionMap((x/2), (y/2)-1); // Inky
              playingGhosts.push_back(g);

              g.set_positionMap((x/2),(y/2)); // Pokey
              playingGhosts.push_back(g);*/


              //cout << "Numero de fantasmas en vector: " << playingGhosts.size() << endl;

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutSpecialFunc(specialkeyboard);

    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    /*Especifica la matriz actual para realizar la composición. En ogl las operaciones de rotación, translación, escalado, etc. se
     * realizan a través de matrices de transformación. Dependiendo de lo que estemos tratando, hay tres tipos de matriz (que son
     * los tres posibles flags que puede llevar de parámetro la función): matriz de proyección (GL_PROJECTION),
     * matriz de modelo (GL_MODELVIEW) y matriz de textura (GL_TEXTURE). Con esta función indicamos a cual de estas tres deben
     * afectar las operaciones. Concretamente, GL_PROJECTION afecta a las vistas o perspectivas o proyecciones.
     */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

              /*glOrtho() define una perspectiva ortonormal. Esto quiere decir que lo que se ves será una proyección paralela en uno de los
               * planos definidos por los ejes. Los parámetros sirven para delimitar el volumen de vista y son, por este orden:
               * x_mínima, x_máxima, y_mínima, y_máxima, z_mínima, z_máxima, (estos dos últimos no son coordenadas como los cuatro primeros,
               * son distancias desde el punto de vista, positivas hacia donde apunta y negativas hacia el lado contrario) considerando que,
               * por defecto, el punto de vista está en el origen de coordenadas mirando hacia el eje negativo de z, estos valores son
               * desplazamientos desde este punto. Con estos seis valores se define el volumen que incluirá los objetos que se proyecten.*/

              gluOrtho2D(0,WIDTH-1,0,HEIGHT-1);

              //Esta función cede el control del flujo del programa a GLUT que, a partir de estos "eventos", irá llamando a las funciones que han sido pasadas como callbacks.
              glutMainLoop();
              return 0;

}

//la función display() al ser pasada a glutDisplayFunc(), será llamada cada vez que haya que redibujar la ventana


void display()
{
    //int starti,startj;

    /*Con esto se define el color con el que se borrara el buffer al hacer un glClear().
     * Los 3 primeros parámetros son las componentes R, G y B, siguiendo un rango de [0..1]. La última es el valor alpha.
     */
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    /* Borra un buffer o una combinación de varios. En este caso, borra el buffer de color (en realidad, cada componente
    R G y B tienen un buffer distinto, pero aquí los trata como el mismo), el que se pinta después en pantalla.
    Para borrarlos utiliza el color que ha sido previamente definido en init() mediante glClearColor(), en este caso,
    el (0,0,0,0) es decir, pinta todo el buffer de negro.*/
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  m.drawMaze(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  myPacman.draw();

  if(ghosts > 0)
  Blinky.draw(1.0,0.0,0.0);

  if(ghosts > 1)
  Pinky.draw(0.73,0.56,0.56);

  if(ghosts > 2)
  Inky.draw(0.0,1.0,1.0);

  if(ghosts > 3)
  Pokey.draw(1.0,0.5,0.0);

  //movimiento fantasmas, no sirve
  /*for(int i = 0; i < playingGhosts.size(); i++)
     {
      playingGhosts[i].draw();

      startj = playingGhosts[i].get_positionMapJ();
      starti = playingGhosts[i].get_positionMapI();

      cout << "Fantasma " << i << "Pos j: " << startj << endl;
      cout << "Fantasma " << i << "Pos i: " << starti << endl;

      m.moveGhost(starti,startj);


      startj = playingGhosts[i].get_positionMapJ();
          starti = playingGhosts[i].get_positionMapI();

          cout << "FantasmaPost " << i << "Pos j: " << startj << endl;
          cout << "FantasmaPost " << i << "Pos i: " << starti << endl;

     }*/





  //to-do comment
  glutSwapBuffers();

  //Le dice al procesador de eventos de GLUT que la ventana actual necesita ser redibujada
  //glutPostRedisplay();

}




/*-----------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------
void display()
{
  glClearColor(0,0,0,0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  myPacman.draw();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
*/
//-----------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------
void keyboard(unsigned char c,int x,int y)
{
  Ghost glocal;
  switch(c)
    {
    case 27: // ESC
          exit (0);
          break;
    case 43: // key '+' to add a ghost  //could be 65 (a) o 97(A)
        // Siempre insertamos en el mismo sitio, podemos mirar de cambiar el sitio. Nota posicion x e y en mapa.
        ghosts++;
         glocal.set_positionMap((x/2) - 1, (y/2) -1);
         playingGhosts.push_back(glocal);
         cout << "Añadimos fantasma. Numero de fantasmas en vector: " << playingGhosts.size() << endl;
         break;
    case 45: // key '-' to remove a ghost  //could be 81 (q) o 113 (Q)
            //Nos aseguramos de que siempre haya al menos un fantasma jugando
        if (ghosts > 1) ghosts--;
             if (playingGhosts.size() > 1) {
                 playingGhosts.pop_back();
                 cout << "Eliminamos fantasma. Numero de fantasmas en vector: " << playingGhosts.size() << endl;
             }
             else cout << "No podemos eliminar fantasma. Al menos tiene que haber un fantasma en juego.Numero de fantasmas en vector: " << playingGhosts.size() << endl;
            // playingGhosts.pop_back();
            break;

   }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void specialkeyboard(int key,int x,int y)
{
    /*
if ( myPacman.getState() == QUIET) // Creo que necesario si avanzamos d muchos en muchos...
{*/
    switch(key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            goNorth();
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            goSouth();
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
             myPacman.moveWest(m, s);
            //goWest();
            break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            myPacman.moveEast(m, s);
            cout << "Maze esta bien: " << m.getRows() << endl;
            //goEast();
            break;
            //Falta igual un default

    //}
}
    //glutPostRedisplay();
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

My pacman class implementation:

```
#include "Pacman.h"




namespace RandomMaze {

Pacman::Pacman() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Pacman::~Pacman() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

//-----------------------------------------------
void Pacman::moveEast(Maze m, Screen s)
{
                    int starti,startj, endi, endj;

                    int relacionAncho=int(s.getWidth() / m.getColumns());
                    int relacionAlto= int(s.getHeigth() / m.getRows());
                    int ysim;
                    cout << "relacionAnchoDentro : " << relacionAncho << endl;
                    cout << "relacionAltoDentro :  " << relacionAlto << endl;

                    starti = m.getPacmanX();
                    startj = m.getPacmanY();
                    cout << "Pacman posicion inicial i D: " << starti << endl;
                    cout << "Pacman posicion inicial j D: " << startj << endl;

                    ysim=0;
                    ysim=m.getRows();
                    cout << "PacmanX numero rows D: " << ysim << endl;
                    ysim= ysim-starti;
                    cout << "PacmanX ysim resultante: D" << ysim << endl;

                    set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);
                    cout << "Set positicion Screen Ancho D: " << startj*relacionAncho << " Alto: D" << ysim*relacionAlto << endl;

                    if ( m.isPassageOrFood( starti, startj+1)) // Si el map de arriba es visitable
                                { //actualizo posicion de pacman
                                m.deleteFood(starti,startj);
                                m.setPacman(starti,startj+1); // NO FOOD PORQUE YA HE PASADO
                                //myPacman.set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,starti*relacionAlto);//  map[x][y-1]=PACMAN; //El sitio de arriba es pacman
                                    //myPacman.init_movement(x,y-1, 1000);
                                //m.drawMaze(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                                startj++;
                                }


                    //colocacion pacman

                    /** Aqui hay algo mal calculado
                                         * La posiciones iniciales van al reves y no estan bien calculadaslo que va tan rapido que no lo vemos
                                         * el set position aqui no hace falta**/
                    /** PACMAN vota, seguro q hay alguna doble inicializacion de la posicion inicial */

                    endi=starti;
                                endj=startj;
                                cout << "Posicion final i: D" << endi << endl;
                                cout << "Posicion final j: D" << endj << endl;

                            //  set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);
                            //  cout << "Me voy a mover desde x: D" << startj*relacionAncho << endl;
                            //  cout << "Me voy a mover desde y: D" << starti*relacionAlto << endl;

                            //  ysim=m.getRows()-endi;
                                //myPacman.set_position(y*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);PACMAN_SPEED
                                init_movement(endj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto, 100); //RATIO hace votar a PACMAN
                                cout << "Me voy a mover hasta x: D" << endj*relacionAncho << endl;
                                cout << "Me voy a mover hasta y: D" << ysim*relacionAlto << endl;

}



//-----------------------------------------------
void Pacman::moveWest(Maze m, Screen s)
{
                    int starti,startj, endi, endj;

                    int relacionAncho=int(s.getWidth() / m.getColumns());
                    int relacionAlto= int(s.getHeigth() / m.getRows());
                    int ysim;
                    cout << "relacionAnchoDentro : " << relacionAncho << endl;
                    cout << "relacionAltoDentro :  " << relacionAlto << endl;

                    starti = m.getPacmanX();
                    startj = m.getPacmanY();
                    cout << "Pacman posicion inicial i D: " << starti << endl;
                    cout << "Pacman posicion inicial j D: " << startj << endl;

                    ysim=0;
                    ysim=m.getRows();
                    cout << "PacmanX numero rows D: " << ysim << endl;
                    ysim= ysim-starti;
                    cout << "PacmanX ysim resultante: D" << ysim << endl;

                    set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);
                    cout << "Set positicion Screen Ancho D: " << startj*relacionAncho << " Alto: D" << ysim*relacionAlto << endl;

                    if ( m.isPassageOrFood( starti, startj-1)) // Si el map de arriba es visitable
                                                        { //actualizo posicion de pacman
                                                        m.deleteFood(starti,startj);
                                                        m.setPacman(starti,startj-1); // NO FOOD PORQUE YA HE PASADO
                                                        //  map[x][y-1]=PACMAN; //El sitio de arriba es pacman
                                                            //myPacman.init_movement(x,y-1, 1000);
                                                        //myPacman.set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,starti*relacionAlto);

                                                        //m.drawMaze(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                                                        startj--;
                                                        }

                    //colocacion pacman

                    /** Aqui hay algo mal calculado
                                         * La posiciones iniciales van al reves y no estan bien calculadaslo que va tan rapido que no lo vemos
                                         * el set position aqui no hace falta**/
                    /** PACMAN vota, seguro q hay alguna doble inicializacion de la posicion inicial */

                    endi=starti;
                                endj=startj;
                                cout << "Posicion final i: D" << endi << endl;
                                cout << "Posicion final j: D" << endj << endl;

                            //  set_positionScreen(startj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);
                            //  cout << "Me voy a mover desde x: D" << startj*relacionAncho << endl;
                            //  cout << "Me voy a mover desde y: D" << starti*relacionAlto << endl;

                            //  ysim=m.getRows()-endi;
                                //myPacman.set_position(y*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto);PACMAN_SPEED
                                init_movement(endj*relacionAncho,ysim*relacionAlto, 100); //RATIO hace votar a PACMAN
                                cout << "Me voy a mover hasta x: D" << endj*relacionAncho << endl;
                                cout << "Me voy a mover hasta y: D" << ysim*relacionAlto << endl;

}

void Pacman::draw()
{

   glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);
  //Draw Circle
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                //Change the 6 to 12 to increase the steps (number of drawn points) for a smoother circle
                //Note that anything above 24 will have little affect on the circles appearance
                //Play with the numbers till you find the result you are looking for
                //Value 1.5 - Draws Triangle
                //Value 2 - Draws Square
                //Value 3 - Draws Hexagon
                //Value 4 - Draws Octagon
                //Value 5 - Draws Decagon
                //Notice the correlation between the value and the number of sides
                //The number of sides is always twice the value given this range
                for(double i = 0; i < 2 * PI; i += PI / 6) //<-- Change this Value
                    glVertex3f(cos(i) * RADIUS + x+7.5, sin(i) * RADIUS + y-10, 0.0);
            glEnd();
            //Draw Circle
}

void Pacman::drawPacman()
{
  glColor3f(1,1,1);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glVertex2i(x-6,y-6);
  glVertex2i(x+6,y-6);
  glVertex2i(x+6,y+6);
  glVertex2i(x-6,y+6);
  glEnd();
}

} /* namespace RandomMaze */
```

So the basic idea: i lookup at the map if i want to go West ( left arrow): if i can ( is passage or food), then i update the position in the map of mypacman ( using m.setPacman(i,j)) and calculate the screen coordinates and init_movement to those coordinates ( pacman is an inherited class from particle) .

```
void particle::init_movement(int destination_x,int destination_y,int duration)
{
  vx = (destination_x - x)/duration;
  vy = (destination_y - y)/duration;

  state=MOVE;
  time_remaining=duration;
}
```

When i moveEast the first time the screen goes black, and the second one gives the error:
Error in `/home/eduardo/Desarrollo/adttrabajos/RandomMaze/Debug/RandomMaze': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f40dd418db8 ***

The same happens with MoveWest

I guess that as i update the position or change maze inside the operation, some kind of free is launched without my knowledge.

Thanks

pd: maze.h

```
#define WALL 0
#define PASSAGE 1
#define FOOD 2
#define VISITED 9
#define RATIO 0.4

//Personajes
#define PACMAN 10 //Comecocos, amarillo

#define BLINKY 11  //Fantasma Rojo ( cazador)
#define PINKY 12  //Fantasma Rosa( emboscador)
#define INKY  13 //Fantasma Azul, cian ( caprichoso)
#define POKEY  14  //Fantasma Naranja ( bobo)




namespace RandomMaze {

/** Esta clase genera y gestiona el laberinto del juego. */
class Maze {

    private:
        int previousBlinky = BLINKY;
        int previousPinky = PINKY;
        int previousInky = INKY;
        int previousPokey = POKEY;

        //Atributos publicos
    public:
        int **map;
        int rows, columns;
        int level;

    //Metodos privados
    private:
        void fillMaze();
        void addBorders();
        void centerWalls();
        void addWalls();
        void exploreMaze(int fila, int columna);
        void checkWalls(int fila, int columna);
        void checkWalls();
        bool isConnected();
        bool isCenter(int r, int c);
        void getaway();
        int isWall(int level);
        void deleteBrick(int i, int j);
        void addFood();
        void addPacman();
        void addBlinky();
        void addPinky();
        void addInky();
        void addPokey();

    //Metodos públicos
    public:
        Maze();
        ~Maze(void);
        Maze(int filas, int columnas, int level);
        double getN();
        void setupMaze(int filas, int columnas, int level);
        void moveGhost(int fila, int columna);
        void printMaze();
        void setRows(int filas);
        void setColumns(int columnas);
        void setLevel(int nivel);
        int getRows();
        int getColumns();
        int getLevel();
        int** getMaze();
        // Pacman
        int getPacmanX();
        int getPacmanY();
        void setPacman( int x,int j);

        //Blinky
        int getBlinkyX();
        int getBlinkyY();
        void setBlinky( int x,int j);
        void setPreviousBlinky(int x,int j);

        //Pinky
        int getPinkyX();
        int getPinkyY();
        void setPinky( int x,int j);
        void setPreviousPinky(int x,int j);

        //INKY
        int getInkyX();
        int getInkyY();
        void setInky( int x,int j);
        void setPreviousInky(int x,int j);

        //POKEY
        int getPokeyX();
        int getPokeyY();
        void setPokey( int x,int j);
        void setPreviousPokey(int x,int j);

        void drawMaze(int width, int height);
        bool isPassageOrFood( int x, int y);
        void deleteFood(int x,int y);

};


} /* namespace RandomMaze */
```

Comment: what do you mean with map? std::map or something else

Comment: You need to debug and find the failing code.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put it maze is a class that has a bidimensional array called map where i put a number in each position a number to identify if there is a wall, corridor, food etc... map[i][j]... id edit the question right now. Thanks

Comment: tl;dr... can the error be narrowed down to a specific part of all that code?

Comment: @TheApache is a runtime error and i think its related to scope of maze because it happens the second time i moveWest.. ive been debugging and is all i can guess right now..i think i need some help with scope and pointers...

Comment: try writing smaller classes with smaller methods, you Maze class is a beast and having large methods make them difficult to read.

Comment: @risingDarkness sorry for my bad english. The problem is that i use a global variable Maze m in the main... and when i use either moveWest or moveEast, when the operation is finished it gives the error... again my guess is that something related to pointer as i change the value of maze inside moveEast...perhaps maze m is liberated ( free) inside the operation..

Comment: Narrowing down a problem you might have to a *minimum* piece of code is an *essential* programmer skill. You *need* to cultivate that skill, or programming will always be a pain to you (and to those you ask to help you).

Comment: Sorry, that last one was a bit on the short side. What I mean is, you have a problem with your memory management. Your example code should therefore be *only* about that memory management. Copy your code, then start cutting away. GLUT functions? Unnecessary. The ghosts? Unnecessary. Walls? Unnecessary. Keep cutting, isolating the problem. You either find the problem yourself, or end up with a handful of lines you can post. -- While we're at it, I made it a habit of always using English for identifiers *and comments*. Your comments are useless for the majority of readers here...

Comment: Shouldn't you pass maze by reference, not by value? Try moveEast(Maze &m, Screen &s)

Comment: The problem was detected afterwards i execute a movement with an arrow. The solution was given below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Pacman::moveWest(Maze m, Screen s)
```

There is your problem.

When you call this function the copy constructor of `Maze` and `Screen` gets called. After the function returns the destructor gets called on the created objects. The default auto-generated copy constructor will simply copy all members to the new object (including the int** map pointer. Then when it gets destroyed that pointer gets freed but the original maze still holds a reference to that pointer and the next time that function gets called the double free error will occur.

What you want is pass a reference or a pointer to Maze (and possibly Screen as well):

```
void Pacman::moveWest(Maze* m, Screen* s)
```

To avoid such a mistake you should at least declare the copy constructor and the assignment operator. This means following the rule of 3 which states that if a class has a destructor it should also have a copy constructor and a assignment operator. There is also a rule of 5 which says you need to have the move variants as well.